# Java Hibernate plugin link for Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I want to have Hibernate Tool to be used in Eclipse. Can anyone give some proper link for the same. I used the following link. It gives an exe file but it is corrupted :
 http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=131065&filename=easy-jboss-hibernate-tools-3.2.0.beta9.exe

Comment: "Hibernate Tool" is a little vague.  What specifically do you want the tool to do (no, I'm not going to try and puzzle it out from that .exe file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install using the the Eclipse built-in update/ install manager which can be accessed by clicking **Help---> Install New Software** .It is the most easiest way to install eclipse plugin IMO.

Hibernate Tool is one of the tools from the JBoss Tools plugin , you can choose to only install Hibernate Tool when installing the JBoss Tools plugin.

[image]

From the [JBoss Tools Website](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html):

> To install via update site, simply right-click the [link below](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html) from
>   which you'd like to install, copy the link, and paste it into
>   Eclipse's Update or Install Manager. See Installing JBoss Tools for
>   more information.

Check the most updated links for different eclipse version from the above [link](https://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html) and refer to this [guide](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_2.html) for the installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you Ken Chan. The link shown in the snapshot you gave worked and just choosed the Hibernate Tool from the list. I got the Hibernarte perspective as well as tools for creating Mapping and Configuration files. :)